# Problema quando tento salvar dados no banco Mysql no Android

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um projeto Android que utiliza a biblioteca Ion para se comunicar com o banco de dados Mysql, porem, quando tento salva os dados, aparece este erro:

Log:

```
 08-20 09:23:28.981 2365-2895/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados W/IonConscrypt: Conscrypt initialization failed.

   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller;

      at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:58)

      at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:75)

      at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.getSocket(ConscryptMiddleware.java:103)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.executeAffinity(AsyncHttpClient.java:301)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.access$100(AsyncHttpClient.java:51)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$1.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:190)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:740)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:758)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:658)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:44)

      at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$14.run(AsyncServer.java:600)

      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
      "com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller" on path: 
      DexPathList[[zip file 
      "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
      1/base.apk", zip file 
      "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
      1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file 
      "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
      1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file 
      "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
       1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file 
       "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
        1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file 
       "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
        1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file 
        "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
         1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file 
         "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
         1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file 
         "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
         1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file 
         "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
          1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file 
         "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
         1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file 
         "/data/app/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados-
         1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
         [/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)

         at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:58) 

         at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:75) 

         at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.getSocket(ConscryptMiddleware.java:103) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.executeAffinity(AsyncHttpClient.java:301) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.access$100(AsyncHttpClient.java:51) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$1.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:190) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:740) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:758) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:658) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:44) 

         at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$14.run(AsyncServer.java:600) 

         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller

         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)

         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)

         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)

         ... 12 more

        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
       08-20 09:23:58.971 2365-2365/com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.gson.JsonElement com.google.gson.JsonObject.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

        at com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados.activity.NovoClienteActivity$1$1.onCompleted(NovoClienteActivity.java:48)

        at com.lp3bmobi.app.controlechamados.activity.NovoClienteActivity$1$1.onCompleted(NovoClienteActivity.java:45)

        at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:107)

        at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:141)

        at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:124)

        at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:244)

        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:60)

        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

Então meu grande, sobre o erro, parece ser um lance de dependencia, verifique se chamou e configurou todas as dependências, se estiver usando o Android Studio ele já irá te informar sobre, senão verifique a versão para o android que deseja compilar e a compatibilidade desse Ion para ele.
Agora se esta usando o MySQL local sugiro usar o Sqlite que será melhor e mais rápido no quesito desempenho, veja mais em https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Se está tentando conexão direta com o MySQL em um servidor externo, sugiro o uso de um api/webservice/rpc para lhe ajudar a gerenciar isso e não precisar ficar abrindo conexão mobile direto com seu banco de dados. Dessa forma é melhor pois depois pode até implementar sistema de token e controle de acesso por api.